# SwiftUI: Layout change to right-to-left isn't working on build

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I changed the layout from leftToRight to rightToLeft. It seems to be working fine on the Canvas view, but when I run it on my phone it's reverted back to leftToRight.

```
struct RegisterView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    Group {
        RegisterView(showReg: .constant(true))
            .preferredColorScheme(.light)
            .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You change it only for Preview, to keep it persistent move that modifier below `Form` inside `RegisterView`.

Comment: Easy fix, thank you!